# How to add Curve walls in libGdx to a world?

Tags: libgdx, curve

I'm making a game, where walls (static bodies) are supposed to simultaneously be appearing (growing) on the screen in shape of different curves. I have no idea how to achieve this. Maybe somehow attaching circle shaped fixtures 1 by 1? I really hope you could set me up on a right direction. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use CircleShapes and stick them together in a curve?

It's much easier and more efficient to use an [EdgeShape](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/EdgeShape.html) where you can define "Lines" of vertices to form any shape. Put the vertices close enough together and they'll form something curvy.

Comment: Yes thanks, but how would I be able to efficiently store a refrence to them as a whole later? If for example I needed to set a specific collision effect to them?

Comment: @user2685747 You do plan to use Box2D, right? Your question sure sounds like that. In this case Have an Entity/Actor (if you use Stage) `Wall` with the Body (which in turn has a Fixture, which in turn has the EdgeShape). Use Body.setUserData(wall) to store a reference to your Entity/Actor. In your collision callback from Box2D you may get the Entity/Actor via `contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData()`.

Comment: Thanks alot, my last question was a bit off, I got it now :)